# How do I write a SCons builder that finds implicit dependencies

Tags: builder, scons, implicit

First: Is it possible to write your own way of finding additional dependencies (eg #included headers) and somehow submit them back to your own custom builder?

Second: If not, is it possible to use SCons's hard-coded #include dependency-detecting system in a custom builder?

Third: If not, can I replace say the Object() builder[?]'s compiler with my own (say a custom llvm with some custom global options) and have it also take per-object options (like multiple per-object -iquote ) while still having it add #included headers as dependencies?

---

A side question: Is there a better build tool I should be using, instead of SCons, where I can write custom builders/tools/commands and manually get those tools to somehow supply custom dependencies (eg: use gcc's -H or -M options and convert them into the build tool's input format).

I have hacked up make to achieve this but it's ultra-verbose and I've resorted to preprocessing makefiles (and then using sed to add tabs). (Which I might throw out here later on as a question / example).

---

---

Ok, I now have

`import SCons.Scanner
env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'T_s2r' : Builder(action = 'g++ -x c++ -std=c++11 -o $TARGET $SOURCE $OPTS', source_scanner = SCons.Scanner.C.CScanner())})
env.T_s2r("gen/run/proj.run", "code/src/main.cpp", OPTS = "-iquote code/include")`

This doesn't update when I alter a header, though.

---

Ah - Scanner needs a search path.

`my_scanner = SCons.Scanner.C.CScanner()
my_scanner.path = FindPathDirs('code/include')
...
Builder(... source_scanner = my_scanner) ...
...`

Still no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do what you are asking in your first question, using [SCons Scanners](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-scanners). Considering the answer to your first question is yes, the other two dont need to be answered :)

As for your side question, SCons is very flexible, and very extensible. Adding custom builders and tools is quite simple, and I dont know of any other build tools with this much flexibility.

Comment: Looks like just what I want. Do you know how I attach the standard #include scanner to my new builder? The documentation is tricky to a almost-no-python-coder. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I think I'm close. ///// import SCons.Scanner /////
env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'T_s2r' : Builder(action = 'g++ -x c++ -std=c++11 -o $TARGET $SOURCE $OPTS', source_scanner = SCons.Scanner.C.CScanner())}) ///// 
env.T_s2r("gen/run/proj.run", "code/src/main.cpp", OPTS = "-iquote code/include") ///// Doesn't rebuild when I alter a header, though.